# Add attribute to root element in schema XML

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a root element named "Project". This root contains type named "Layer", but I don't know how to define attributes to the root (Project) element.

This attribute which want add to root:

```
 <attribute name="name" type="string" />
 <attribute name="location" type="string" />
 <attribute name="Description" type="string" />
 <attribute name="CreationDate" type="string" />
```

This my schema:

```
 <element name="Project" type="tns:Layer"></element>

 <complexType name="Layer">
        <sequence>
            <element name="LayerName" type="string" maxOccurs="1"
                minOccurs="0">
            </element>
            <element name="Order" type="integer"></element>
            <element name="Visible" type="boolean"></element>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="id" type="integer"></attribute>
    </complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your schema has just *one* element. It's *type* is called `Layer`. That means that `<Project>` can contain the elements `<LayerName>`, `<Order>` and `<Visible>` as well as an *attribute* named `id`.

If you want to **add** attributes to the `Project` element, you just have to place the attribute declarations after the one that already exists for ID:

```
<complexType name="Layer">
    <sequence>
        <element name="LayerName" type="string" maxOccurs="1"
            minOccurs="0">
        </element>
        <element name="Order" type="integer"></element>
        <element name="Visible" type="boolean"></element>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="id" type="integer"></attribute>
    <attribute name="name" type="string"/>
    <attribute name="location" type="string" />
    <attribute name="Description" type="string" />
    <attribute name="CreationDate" type="string" />
</complexType>
```

Now you can use:

```
<Project name="..." location="..." ... > ... </Project>
```

Comment: thanks for help me. If I put attribute same "name, location, description" inside tag layer, that mean this attribute for layer not for project!!!. I want add "name, location, description" to project.

Comment: There is no tag `<layer>` in your schema. `Layer` is the **type** of `<Project>`. The attributes placed inside the `Layer` complexType are to be used in `<Project>` because `<element name="Project" type="tns:Layer">` declares that.